# Why they print four color circles on bottom of the newspaper?

Tags: news

Why do they print four color circles on bottom of the newspaper? [image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with UX, and everything to do with printing techniques and technology.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that is a test for the different colors of ink. The newspaper is probably printed in CMYK, which means they use cyan, magenta, and yellow inks to do colors (and black for grayscale). In order to make sure all the inks are showing up the way they should, they print circles (sometimes squares) at the bottom so they have a solid swatch of color to look at/test against.

Comment: In addition they sometimes print "targets" with different colors near or on top of each other. These are used to check for correct alignment of all colors if the newspaper is printed one color at a time in several passes. [Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r9eE4.jpg).

Comment: ...and black. That's the K in CMYK